# How i will be able to release port used by Ants Performance Software So That I Will be able to restart my IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, dotnet-httpclient, ants

I am facing one problem while using Ants Performance Software. I am using it for monitoring my IIS. I used it for monitoring my IIS for long hours like more than 8 hours.Then Ants Performance software got hanged And now I am not able to even stop it. And that port number is also getting locked means Ants Performance is not releasing that port. So now even I am not able to restart my IIS. Because it is throwing message that this port is getting used by some other application. Please help anyone how to handle this.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir, But I need other way's because my server i am operating remotely.What you have given suggestion i tried it locally and it worked. But what if i remotely access my Server.

Comment: Remote into the server and reboot?

Comment: Thanks sir. I got it.